# How to activate Localizations in Cordova / Xcode for a storyboard added via a Cordova plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, meteor

### The tldr:

We have a few storyboards that we add via (our own) cordova plugins that need localizing. How can we set up the plugins so that their localizations are taken into account by xcode, without having to touch xcode.

### The Backstory:

Adding a localization to a cordova project normally requires clicking the project in the file browser, choosing Project, and clicking on the `+` icon in the Localization section. Having to go through this process in normal iOS development is fine because it you're not recreating the Xcode project all the time.

Cordova on the other hand likes to recreate the Xcode project from scratch at various points throughout development, and if you're using meteor like we are, the xcode project will automatically get recreated multiple times a day. So it'd be nice to have a solution that doesn't require digging through xcode settings and renaming / overwriting translation files etc.